# Have a button send an AJAX put request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm not so familiar with ajax and need some assistance. I'm successfully looping through a json feed and outputting the info inside it's own div. Each object has a boolean attached. Based on if the boolean is true or false some css classes change. I'm wondering how to have the inline button set the current object from false to true. Below is my code. There is zero HTML, jquery is creating the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Layout Output
    $('body').prepend('<div class="container"></div>');
    container = $('.container');
    $(container).append('<div class="quickselect"><select id="selectField"></select></div>');

    selectDropDown = $('#selectField');
    $(selectDropDown).append('<option value="option1">Class1</option><option value="option2">Class 2</option>');

    options = [];
    options.push('<div id="option1" class="box"><p>12/13/2012</p><p>1:00:00 PM</p><p>Auditorium B</p></div>');
    options.push('<div id="option2" class="box"><p>12/13/2012</p><p>1:00:00 PM</p><p>Auditorium A</p></div>');

    $(selectDropDown).after(options);

    $(container).append('<div class="userlist"></div>');
    userList = $('.userlist');
    $(userList).prepend('<button>Set All as Attended</button>')

    users = [];

    users.push('<div class="usercontainer">Dillon Raphael1 <button>Set as Attended</button></div>');
    users.push('<div class="usercontainer">Dillon Raphael2 <button>Set as Attended</button></div>');
    users.push('<div class="usercontainer">Dillon Raphael3 <button>Set as Attended</button></div>');

    fetchUsers = function() {
        $.getJSON("http://www.json-generator.com/j/cuPmRkQQjm?indent=4", function( data ) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                if(val.attended == true) {
                users.push('<div class="usercontainer">' + val.name +' ' + val.attended + '<button type="button" disabled class="attended">Attended</button></div>');
                } else {
                users.push('<div class="usercontainer">' + val.name +' ' + val.attended + '<button class="unattended">Set as Attended</button></div>'); 
                }
            });

            $(userList).append(users);
        });
    }
    fetchUsers();
});
```

The button that is going to be pressed to change the boolean value is

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.userlist').on('click', 'button', function(event){
  var $button = $(event.currentTarget);
  var $container = $button.closest('.usercontainer');
  //now you can change data- attributes of div.usercontainer or classes...
  $container.data('attended', true);
  $container.toggleClass('attended unattended');
  //etc.
});
```

is it what you need?